# Solving Storyboard missing trailing/leading constraints warning

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, constraints

I'm shipping my app for all iPhone models (iOS 10.0+) and have made sure that in all localisations, labels and controls will not overlap.

In a simple static cell, it would be enough to give the label on the left side a leading constraint and center it vertically. The same would be done with the control on the right, but with a trailing constraint. All would be fine.

Until Xcode warning.

It asks for missing trailing or leading constraints to avoid overlapping in any case (which would not happen in mine).

Here is a simple test case:
[image: Here is a simple test case:]

I silenced the warning by giving a switch on the right a leading constraint of 10.0, just to make sure. It works fine. (Attached image first row)

The same, however, with a segmented control would stretch it all the way to the left to the right side of the label. Attached image 3rd row) Even if I increased the size of the label further to the right it would stomp the width of the label.

Since I'd like to have the cell as in the 2nd row, I did what I considered hacky in the view controller, in which case I'd have to specify exact x values for each screen size (which is ok, but I'd like to avoid) (Storyboards, after all...):

```
@IBOutlet weak var mySegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    mySegmentedControl.frame = CGRect(x: 238.0, y: mySegmentedControl.frame.minY,
                                      width: 121.0, height: mySegmentedControl.frame.height)
  }
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: use grater than or equal to constant as trailing value will fix the warning.

Comment: @LaI Krishna thank you for the help, where would I specify that?

Comment: you can quick fix by clicking on the **Yellow Right Arrow** near the `My Table View Controller Scene` text.

Comment: I see, only after adding, in this case a trailing constant of, say, 10, I could edit it in the Size Inspector.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the quick fix! That was easier than I expected. If could post this as an answer for anyone else coming along here I can accept this as the answer.

Comment: glad that i could help you. I just added it as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51516815/4061501). Please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New versions of Xcode will show this as a warning.

You could fix this Adding greater than or Equal constraint to UILabel's trailing.

NB: you can quick fix by clicking on the *Yellow Right Arrow* near the `My Table View Controller Scene` text

The `UILabel` is variable in length. When you set text to label, it will resize automatically. If you are not setting the Trailing Constraint it may overlaps other views (in this case - segmented control). It will work if you add fixed constraint, but new Xcode shows it as warning. So we have to change it as greater or lesser than constraints.

Comment: That's great, like that I was able to fix 20 of these warnings in 2 mins.

Comment: quick fix works for almost cases. But Sometimes it cause trouble. Like adding constraints inside Scrollview.